# Insert file into appdata folder

Tags: objective-c, google-drive-api

I am developing Mac application and want to store file in Google drive.The files should be hidden from the user.So my choice is to save in "appdata" folder. Using [Drive sample code](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-objectivec-client/)   to upload file. To insert file into "appdata" folder am using this [sample code](https://developers.google.com/drive/appdata). But when I insert the file is visible to user.It is not hidden.

1. So Please let me know what are the changes necessary [Drive sample
   code](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-objectivec-client/) to upload file into "appdata" private folder. ?
2. Do I need
   to create "appdata" folder for the first time?

Comment: You don't have to create "appdata" folder and it should be invisible to user. Could you provide further information? Is the code you used this one? https://developers.google.com/drive/appdata#inserting_a_file_into_the_application_data_folder

Comment: @JunYoung Gwak Thanks for the info. Yes, I am using[this sample to insert|upload file to appdata folder](https://developers.google.com/drive/appdata#inserting_a_file_into_the_application_data_folder).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After doing following changes to [Drive Sample](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-objectivec-client/) successfully uploaded file to app data folder:

1. Modified API scope to choose "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.appdata" :

`GTMOAuth2WindowController *windowController = [GTMOAuth2WindowController controllerWithScope:@"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.appdata"
                                                                                                clientID:clientID
                                                                                            clientSecret:clientSecret
                                                                                        keychainItemName:kKeychainItemName
                                                                                          resourceBundle:frameworkBundle];`

2.Obtain parent file reference. Here 'appdata' folder is the parent:

```
GTLQuery *query = [GTLQueryDrive queryForFilesGetWithFileId:@"appdata"];
        [service executeQuery:query
            completionHandler:^(GTLServiceTicket *ticket, GTLDriveFile *parentfile,
                                NSError *error) {
                /*Save parentfile for future reference*/}];
```

3.While uploading set file parent to app data folder. Using parent file reference obotained in the previous step

```
GTLDriveParentReference *parentRef = [GTLDriveParentReference object];
        parentRef.identifier = parentfile.identifier;
        fileToUpload.labels.hidden = @YES;
        fileToUpload.parents = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: parentRef, nil];
```

Comment: can you please help me to my question here. http://stackoverflow.com/q/40299477/1201441