# How to Upload & Retrive folder to appDataFolder inside Google Driver IOS App

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-api, google-drive-api

How to upload folder on **appDataFolder of Google Drive** , I am trying to below  code , but not work proper. so, can any buddy please help me regarding uploading folder in Google Drive from IOS App.

```
GTLServiceDrive *drive= [self driveService];
        GTLDriveFile *folder = [GTLDriveFile object];
        folder.mimeType = @"application/vnd.google-apps.folder";
        folder.parents = @[appDataFolder];
        GTLUploadParameters *uploadParameters = [GTLUploadParameters
                                                 uploadParametersWithData:data
                                                 MIMEType:@"application/vnd.google-apps.folder"];
        GTLQueryDrive *query = [GTLQueryDrive queryForFilesCreateWithObject:folder uploadParameters:uploadParameters];
        //query.q = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"appDataFolder"];
        [drive executeQuery:query completionHandler:^(GTLServiceTicket *ticket,
                                                      GTLDriveFile *updatedFile,
                                                      NSError *error) {
            if (error == nil) {

                                } else {

            }
        }];
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the Parents property of your driveFile

```
GTLDriveParentReference *parentRef = [GTLDriveParentReference object];
parentRef.identifier = folderIdentifier; // identifier property of the folder
driveFile.parents = @[ parentRef ];
```